# how to find the roots for this equation?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I encountered the following question while learning about complex numbers. I did reach a solution, yet I feel like I took a long route. I am sure that there are better ways to solve this question. I will share my solution down . If there are any new suggestions with explanation, I would be more than thankful.
find the roots for the following equation
$$x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+10$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have to solve a quartic equation $x^4+\alpha x^3+\beta x^2+\gamma x+\delta=0$, usually the first thing that I do is to apply the substitution $x=y-\frac\alpha4$, because then I get a quartic equation without a cubic term.

In your case, that means to make the substitution $x=y+\frac12$. Note that$$p\left(y+\frac12\right)=y^4-\frac{5y^2}2+\frac{169}{16}.$$Well, not only there is no cubic term, as there is no term of degree $1$. And the roots of this quartic equation (which is a biquadratic equation) are$$\frac32-i,\frac32+i,-\frac32-i,\text{ and }-\frac32+i.$$So, you have\begin{align}p(x)=0&\iff p\left(y+\frac12\right)=0\\&\iff y^4-\frac{5y^2}2+\frac{169}{16}=0\\&\iff y=\frac32-i\vee y=\frac32+i\vee{}\\&\phantom{\iff}\vee y=-\frac32-i\vee y=-\frac32+i\\&\iff x-\frac12=\frac32-i\vee x-\frac12=\frac32+i\vee{}\\&\phantom{\iff}\vee x-\frac12=-\frac32-i\vee x-\frac12=-\frac32+i\\&\iff x=2-i\vee x=2+i\vee x=-1-i\vee x=-1+i.\end{align}

Comment: I did not accept the answer immediately because I wanted to leave a possibility for other suggestions ,your approach certainly was helpful and made me learn a lot thank u

Comment: Of course. When I post a question of this type, I also wait some time until I accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions such as x=$$\pm1,\pm10,\pm5,\pm2 $$
found no real roots
could not write (x+a)*( )
so  went with a different approach
reached 2 equations
$$(x^2+ax\pm 2)(x^2+bx\pm 5)$$
$$(x^2+ax\pm 1)(x^2+bx\pm 10)$$
the coefficient of $$x^3= -2 a+b=-2  b=-2-a$$
checked each one
$$(x^2+ax\pm 1)(x^2+bx\pm 10)$$
I know that the multiplication should result in coefficient 2 for x
$$2=\pm10a\pm(a+2)$$
results in a=0 as a solution ,since the teacher demanded  that a and b are members of z

coefficient of  $$x^3 =1 $$
$$\pm1=\pm10\pm(1-a)(a+2)$$
no solution

$$(x^2+ax\pm 2)(x^2+bx\pm 5)$$
$$2=\pm5a\pm2(a+2)$$
$$\pm(3a-4)$$
$$-1=\pm5\pm2-a(a+2)$$
-1=7-2*4
there is a solution
$$(x^2+2x+ 2)(x^2-4x+ 5)$$
$$((x+1)^2+ 1)((x-2)^2+1)$$
$$(−−2)(−+1)(+−2)(++1)=0 $$
this took a lot of time and a couple of hints to solve any new approaches are welcome